# AZ command to fetch Azure Monitor logs

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I have to fetch logs using AZ commands:

***If I add a filter on Resource Group, it is not giving result.***

For e.g.--
Following commands is working fine:

`az monitor activity-log list --subscription "subscription1"`

In the result I am getting logs for ResourceGroup1.

But when I execute following:

`az monitor activity-log list --resource-group "ResourceGroup1"`

***It is giving 0 result.***

I am using "azure-cli": "2.26.1"

Comment: Just wondering if your resource group (`ResourceGroup1`) exist in the default subscription associated with your account.

Comment: Yes, it is. When I did ```AZ login``` subscription1 was there, which is for ```ResourceGroup1```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to read monitor activity logs at resource group level

```
az monitor activity-log list -g "resource-group"
```

Here is the command to pull [activity monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_activity_log_list) with filters

```
az monitor activity-log list -g 'resource-group' --start-time 2021-07-29T12:00:00 --select {ResourceGroupName,EventTimestamp,CorrelationId,ResourceId} -o table
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we do AZ login, there is one field `"isDefault": true` for only one subscription (Default subscription of your account). For other Subscriptions, it will be False.

You will get results for all RGs under default Subscription. For other RGs, it will give 0 result.

Therefore, when you apply filter on a RG, you need to confirm that it's corresponding Subscription should be set as default. You can set same as:

`az account set -s <subscription ID>`